# PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

How to preg-match total_count
from this code in php

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Baptiste Chimay",
         "administrator": false,
         "id": "10153820811316460"
      },
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 4956
   }
}
```

i tried but it didnt get any data

```
$url = ('the url i want');
                $result = json_decode($url);
    $likes = preg_match("'total_count (.*?),'si", file_get_contents($url), $matches);
print_r($url);
```

Comment: Looks like (partial) json - is that the entire output from that url?

Comment: not the entire output

Comment: Please add the entire output. Php has native support for json, so regex is **not** the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats json data, you can use `json_decode` to create a php array:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($myurl), true);

echo $data['summary']['total_count']; //outputs 4956
```

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the quotes:

```
preg_match("/total_count\"\:(.*?)/i", file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);
//               here __^
```

But, you don't need to escape the selmicolon

```
preg_match("/total_count\":(.*?)/i", file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);
```

you could also replace the double quotes by single quotes:

```
preg_match('/total_count":(.*?)/i', file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);
```

and change the `.*?` to `[^"]+`

```
preg_match("/total_count\":([^"]+)/i", file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);
```

you could also replace the double quotes by single quotes:

```
preg_match('/total_count":(\d+)/i', file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);
```

Comment: I would actually change from the `[^"]` to `d+`

Comment: @mloureiro: you're rigth